# How to add new fields to an existing IIS web site log using Set-WebConfigurationProperty

Tags: powershell, iis

https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/how-change-iis-log-contents-powershell/ tells me how to set default file fields at a service level, helpful :-)
But I want to set the actual file fields (add sc-bytes and cs-bytes) at an individual named web site level - as you can so easily through IIS GUI yes - but so much better to be able to SET and GET (to check) using a repeatable script against multiple IIS web & app servers - yup I would really like to catalogue IIS services with a POSH script ...

So this works beautifully:-

```
Invoke-Command –Session $session {
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter System.Applicationhost/Sites/SiteDefaults/logfile -Name LogExtFileFlags -Value "Date,Time,ClientIP"}
```

.... and I can - thanks to a Stackoverflow tip - use IIS's GUI Config editor to create the same Powershell - at the service level for the default log file settings.

I tried to use the Config editor at the Web site level to add the sc-bytes and cs-bytes fields to the actual log file but the log file does not appear in the list?

I have given up for now and used the GUI.

I have seen others asking similar questions and hoped that we could all get an answer :-)

Comment: Question is VERY unclear. What are you actually looking for? Why `sc-bytes` doesn't work in the server-level command or how to get-set on a site-level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you need to use for the property is not the same as the column-names in the iislog, but values for the enum [`LogExtFileFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.logextfileflags(v=vs.90).aspx). You can use the provided MSDN-link to find the values or set it using GUI on a server and and get the values using `Get-WebConfigurationProperty`. Ex:

```
Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter System.Applicationhost/Sites/SiteDefaults/logfile -Name
LogExtFileFlags
Date,Time,ClientIP,ServerIP,BytesSent,BytesRecv

#This doesn't work because sc-bytes and cs-bytes are not the right values
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter System.Applicationhost/Sites/SiteDefaults/logfile -Name LogExtFileFlags -Value "Date,Time,ClientIP,sc-bytes,cs-bytes"

#However this works
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter System.Applicationhost/Sites/SiteDefaults/logfile -Name LogExtFileFlags -Value "Date,Time,ClientIP,BytesSent,BytesRecv"
```

To get and set logging fields for a specific web site, use:

```
#Get current
PS > (Get-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\' -Name logfile).logExtFileFlags
Date,Time,ClientIP,ServerIP,BytesSent,BytesRecv

#Set new value
PS > Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\' -Name logfile -Value @{logExtFileFlags = "Date,T
ime,ClientIP,ServerIP,BytesSent" }

#Verify
PS > (Get-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\' -Name logfile).logExtFileFlags
Date,Time,ClientIP,ServerIP,BytesSent
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and trouble and sorry to have buried the question, thank you.

Comment: Great. :-) If it solved your problem, remember to close the question by accepting the correct answer.

Comment: Import-Module WebAdministration 

Set-Location IIS:\ 

#Get current
(Get-ItemProperty '.\Sites\Contoso\' -Name logfile).logExtFileFlags

#Set new value
Set-ItemProperty '.\Sites\Contoso\' -Name logfile -Value @{logExtFileFlags = "Date,Time,ClientIP,UserName,ServerIP,Method,UriStem,UriQuery,HttpStatus,Win32Status,BytesSent,BytesRecv,TimeTaken,ServerPort,UserAgent,Referer,HttpSubStatus" }

#Verify
(Get-ItemProperty '.\Sites\Contoso\' -Name logfile).logExtFileFlags

Comment: #It worked perfectly - I can now add the BytesSent,BytesRecv columns and see that I have
#I liked the dotted notation of your answer.
#It was good to be reminded that like SQL server the IIS snapin has the drive metaphor that lets you DIR & CD around the structure - though there are a lot of collections which spoil the simple fun with that - Select * only goes so far
#thank you again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am mostly quoting @Frode solution here. But I was getting this error when invoking the Get-ItemProperty :

```
#Get current
PS > (Get-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\' -Name logfile).logExtFileFlag
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\' -Name logfile).logEx ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (IIS:String) [Get-ItemProperty], DriveNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
```

Weirdly enough to be able to execute the **Get-ItemProperty** on a website name, I had to execute atleast once this command on each machine (Win Server 2019) :

```
PS > Get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter System.Applicationhost/Sites/SiteDefaults/logfile -Name LogExtFileFlags
```

Once it was executed, I was able to reference any website in IIS ans set the fields list :

```
PS > Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Integration Web Service\' -Name logfile -Value @{logExtFileFlags = "Date,Time,ClientIP,UserName,ServerIP,Method,UriStem,UriQuery,HttpStatus,Win32Status,TimeTaken,ServerPort,UserAgent,Referer,Host,HttpSubStatus" }
```

Not sure if there is a reason why I had this behaviour, or if there is a better way to workaround this issue but atleast this fixed it for me.